# Circle(ARC) gradient fill with canvas JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gradient, geometry

I need to draw a dynamic donut chart - something similar to -

```
http://194.90.28.56/~dev1/t.jpg
```

The green part indicates the percentage (in this case 27%) - it must be dynamic.

I think I need to do something like - [Android - How to draw an arc based gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037108/android-how-to-draw-an-arc-based-gradient)

But with JS..

Thanks.

Comment: Not enough info to even start helping!

Answer (score 15):

Great question. Gradients along paths in canvas are hard. The easiest way is to fudge it.

Instead of thinking of your image as a gradient that follows a circular path, think of it as two linear gradients.

- One on the left side, going from green to gray, top to bottom.
- The other on the right side, going from white to gray, top to bottom.

Imagine a square made of those two gradients:

[image]

Now imagine a circle cutting through:

[image]

That's all you gotta do.

To "cut" through like that its easiest to use clipping regions, so I've made an example doing that.

Here's the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/Msdkv/

Code below! Hope that helps.

```
var greenPart = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,100);
greenPart.addColorStop(0, 'palegreen');
greenPart.addColorStop(1, 'lightgray');

var whitePart = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,100);
whitePart.addColorStop(0, 'white');
whitePart.addColorStop(1, 'lightgray');


var width = 20;
ctx.lineWidth = width;

// First we make a clipping region for the left half
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(-width, -width, 50+width, 100 + width*2);
ctx.clip();

// Then we draw the left half
ctx.strokeStyle = greenPart;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50,50,50,0,Math.PI*2, false);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default

// Then we make a clipping region for the right half
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(50, -width, 50+width, 100 + width*2);
ctx.clip();

// Then we draw the right half
ctx.strokeStyle = whitePart;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50,50,50,0,Math.PI*2, false);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is that this should be a donut graph. The green part indicates the percentage. With your solution it won't be possible to show more then 50% (correct me if I'm wrong..).

Comment: You're correct, my solution won't work in that case. Can you update your question to be a lot more specific?

Comment: Done. Thanks, hopefully I will figure this out :)

Comment: Fantastic solution for what I need. +1